# checbox как теги, метки

Tags: html, jquery

есть список чекбоксов, как с помощью jquery сделать их как теги (пример https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/form.html Input Tags)

Comment: сделайте сразу тэги, зачем вам чекбоксы в таком случае?

Comment: затем что мне нужно будет их выбирать и добавлять в базу

Comment: честно сказать, не вижу связи с чекбоксами. Используйте `hidden` поля, а чекбосы вам тут не нужны.